# Newbie python - replace in an array

Tags: python, regex

In a file, I have the following lines

```
NetConn_msa[0].time=0.0

NetConn_msa[1].time=0.0 etc for 60 elements.
```

I need to write a script to change the time from 0.0 to 0.5.

I started with `st.replace("delay=0.0","delay=0.05")` and then tried to find the string to replace

```
sub=re.compile("\[\d+\]\.\w+=[0]\.[0]")
result=sub.search(st)
```

Can someone please help me since I am very new to programming.
Thanks!

Comment: You have not really asked a question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = """NetConn_msa[0].time=0.0

NetConn_msa[1].time=0.0 etc for 60 elements. """

print re.sub("(\]\.\w+)=0.0","\\1=0.5",x)

#NetConn_msa[0].time=0.5

#NetConn_msa[1].time=0.5 etc for 60 elements.
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this the really easy way: manually edit the file so that the offending 60 lines are replaced by:

```
for x in range(60):
    NetConn_msa[x].time = 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
import re

x = """NetConn_msa[0].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[59].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[0].time=9.9
NetConn_msa[60].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[61].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[99].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[100].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[0].other=0.0
NetConn_msa[0].time=0.01
PseudoNetConn_msa[59].time=0.0
Foo[0].bar=0.0"""

print "=== not strict enough ==="
print re.sub("(\]\.\w+)=0.0","\\1=0.5",x)

print "=== stricter ==="
print re.sub(r"(NetConn_msa\[[1-5]?\d\]\.time)=0.0\b", r"\1=0.5", x)
```

Output:

```
=== not strict enough ===
NetConn_msa[0].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[59].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[0].time=9.9
NetConn_msa[60].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[61].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[99].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[100].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[0].other=0.5
NetConn_msa[0].time=0.51
PseudoNetConn_msa[59].time=0.5
Foo[0].bar=0.5
=== stricter ===
NetConn_msa[0].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[59].time=0.5
NetConn_msa[0].time=9.9
NetConn_msa[60].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[61].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[99].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[100].time=0.0
NetConn_msa[0].other=0.0
NetConn_msa[0].time=0.01
PseudoNetConn_msa[59].time=0.0
Foo[0].bar=0.0
```

Comment: I think your "stricter" entry is the same as "no strict enough"

Comment: @Aif: If you mean that my longer version is still not strict enough, please give an example; otherwise, please explain what you mean.

Comment: Sorry it was unclear: look the output. Stricter also matched `Foo[O].bar=0.0`.

Comment: @Aif: You are mistaken. Look at the output. "Stricter" did NOT change the 0.0 to 0.5.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't figure out the "sub" stuff. (was late.. :p)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this the easy way?

st.replace('.time=0.0\n','.time=0.5\n')

Comment: Because you could change text that should not be changed, and not change text that should be changed. Examples of the latter: `'.time=0.0 \n'` and `'.time=0.0 # comment\n'`